# WPExplorer Adapt Theme: only 5 Portfolio images will show

Tags: image-gallery, portfolio

I'm using the Adapt WP explorer theme and I'm having trouble getting images to show in the portfolio. All the images will display on the Portfolio page (http://kefarpublishing.com/testwebsite/kefar-korner-2/), but when you click on the first one, the slider arrows show, but no image. Only the last five images are displayed. I have tried the following:

1. resetting permalinks
2. creating a gallery on the Portfolio page
3. deleting images from media, uploading into gallery

Also, the only way to get the categories to show is by creating a category titled "All," and then it shows all the ones I created, plus an extra All category (so I have two alls and the rest, or no categories at all).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all disable any other plugins and see if your category menu works then. Then activate them one by one to see which one is conflicting. When you find it, just find an alternative plugin for what you need.

It sounds like you're inserting a gallery into your posts which isn't necessary. To display images in the slider, create a portfolio item, then click on set featured image, upload the images you want to appear on the slider (choosing them from the media library won't work, you have to upload to the post) and then update.